# Odoo 10 Project Task Description is not being saved

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

We have a openerp 5.0.3 which we are still using till now, and we are looking into migrating to newer one so I currently studying it.

I have tried Odoo 10 Online and On-premise under VM. but with the same report, basic module PROJECTS-TASK Description Field is not being save no matter how try it.

What seems to be the problem, is it on my side or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

That bug is confirmed and looked into. Look at [the issue on github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14422) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Last night I found a link to a fix for 9.0 like post of @CZoellner:  [github/odoo/issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14351) and down below of the post there is a patch for 10.0 branch created by [7hunderbug](https://github.com/7hunderbug) which works for me.

```
patch -p0 < <(curl 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/7hunderbug/0d100ce4e703dcbe9527dd2c468b0e64/raw/b46a8d9104e875c7e408a76b8a52d95f43f40c8c/Patch%2520for%2520Odoo%252010.0-20161121%2520%28Community%2520Edition%29%2520to%2520revert%2520commit%2520897290dd3f%2520-%2520fixes%2520disappearing%2520task%2520descriptions')
```

Which in his description can be applied from the odoo root directory

I hope this could help others with the same problem